# Are there machine (and human) readable specification languages for algorithm collections and meta-libraries?

Tags: metaprogramming

Is there high-level language out there for describing algorithms, that's geared towards specification, rather than implementation?

The idea would be to have a machine-readable archive of standard algorithms, with machine-readable annotations on trade-offs, and variants.

I'm thinking of something like CycL / OpenCyC, but for algorithms and programming patterns.

Answer (score 3):

These are not exact fits, but they are somewhat close: [Maude](http://maude.cs.uiuc.edu/) and [CASL](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/cofi/wiki/index.php/CASL).  They are both machine-readable (with decent tools) specification languages which also allow some forms of code.  Some people swear by [AsmL](http://asml.codeplex.com/), but I'm not a fan.

Soon I think that [Agda 2](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php) will fulfill that niche quite well, but it's still in full development.  One can also say that [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/) already fulfills that role (because of program extraction), but I am not a fan either.

Answer (score 0):

The glib answer: Yes. It's called English.

The serious answer: No, as you've probably already assumed after months of this question going unanswered. I don't believe there's any real consensus, or even consideration, over what such a language would entail. Programming patterns and algorithms are always changing and evolving, so designing a language that would be able to describe all future patterns would be very difficult, if not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode, possibly.  Or flowcharts.  For machine readable, it would have to be something like a meta-language.  Lisp and Forth come to mind.  Languages that are essentially self-defining, with a small set of primitives to build up the higher layers of abstraction.